# continuity and convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb {R}\to \mathbb {R}$ be such a function such that $f'$ is continuous on $\mathbb {R}$. Show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\{f(\frac{x}{2n})-f(\frac{x}{2n+1})\}$$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Here $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{f(\frac{x}{2n})-f(\frac{x}{2n+1})\}}{\frac{x}{2n}-\frac{x}{2n+1}}(\frac{x}{2n}-\frac{x}{2n+1})$$

Since $f$ is differentiable there exists $c\in (\frac{x}{2n+1},\frac{x}{2n})$, such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{f(\frac{x}{2n})-f(\frac{x}{2n+1})\}}{\frac{x}{2n}-\frac{x}{2n+1}}=f'(c)$$

Now given $f'$ is continuous on $\mathbb {R}$, $f'$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and hence bounded say $M$. Hence  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{f(\frac{x}{2n})-f(\frac{x}{2n+1})\}}{\frac{x}{2n}-\frac{x}{2n+1}}\lt \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} M(\frac{x}{2n}-\frac{x}{2n+1})=M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(2n)(2n+1)}$$
$$\lt M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)}$$. Since the R.H.S converges by weistrass M test so does the given series

Is this alright?

Comment: there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. You have a typo when you use the Mean Value Theorem (the series should not be there). Also, you need to use absolute value in your first inequality (which shows that in fact you show that convergence is absolute).